# MediaElement current state close Unreason

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, mediaelement

My app has been working fine for a lot of months, but now its not working. When I handle the exception, I get: `MediaElement.currentState is Closed`. And get result:"Media Player not avaliable". This my code:

```
if (mediaElement.CurrentState.Equals(MediaElementState.Playing)) {
    mediaElement.Stop();
}
else {
    try {
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);
        // Send the stream to the media object.
        mediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) {
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Media Player not avaliable");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code on my side and I cannot reproduce your issue. Since your code is not completed, I added the remain code by myself and it can run successfully now. Please compare the code snippet to find if something is wrong with your code. You can also run the following simple demo on your machine which can work well on my machine to see if it is a machine environment issue. My test environment is windows 10 build 14393.

XAML Code

```
  <MediaElement   x:Name="mediaElement"
        CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged" Height="200" Width="300" AutoPlay="False"/>
  <Button x:Name="btntest" Click="btntest_Click" Content=" media close test"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
  private async void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (mediaElement.CurrentState.Equals(MediaElementState.Playing))
      {
          mediaElement.Stop();
      }
      else
      {
          try
          { 
              var sin = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
              string texto = "hello world";
              SpeechSynthesisStream stream= await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);                  
              // Send the stream to the media object.
              mediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
              mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
              mediaElement.Play();
          }
          catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
          {
              var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Media Player not avaliable");
              await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
          }
      }
```